# Mounting an SSD that had Ubuntu installed before as an external drive doesnt load anything

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, ssd, external-hard-drive

I have a Samsung SSD 840PRO that had Ubuntu installed on it as OS. Something happened to the computer and I had to unplug the drive, today after many years I got an external SSD enclosure and installed the SSD on it but my Mac doesnt recognize the drive and I can't view anything.

I had some important files on this drive and I am not really sure what to do now.

I went to disk utility on Mac and there are only this info listed for external drive and cant mount it.

[image: only these info]

Any chance I can safely mount this drive to view the files?

**Update #1:**
I ran `diskutil list` and got this info:

```
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *128.0 GB   disk2
   1:                        EFI ⁨NO NAME⁩                 536.9 MB   disk2s1
   2:           Linux Filesystem ⁨⁩                        110.4 GB   disk2s2
   3:                 Linux Swap ⁨⁩                        17.1 GB    disk2s3
```

which is correct, since the SSD is 128GB one.

**Update #2:**
I used a software called iBoysoft and ran the recovery and it was able to extract some pdf files (I stopped at 1%), I am assuming this means the drive is not encrypted? I want to be able to mount this drive to view my all my files.

Comment: It shows swap (partition) only which suggests the rest is an encrypted volume.

Comment: @ChanganAuto any chance I can recover the data?

Comment: If the hypotheses is correct then no. That's what encryption is for.

Comment: I dont think I ever encrypted the files on the drive, it was just a normal Ubuntu installation

Comment: If you selected LVM and or LUCKS the result, in this case, is pretty much the same. In any case you need Linux and LVM tools and/or encryption password/passphrase, etc.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Mac can't read ExtFS natively, so it's unsurprising the data is minimal & it can't be mounted.

Comment: RainMan - in Disk Utility, first click the view icon top left to show the sidebar, then press Cmd/2 which will show all devices, not just volumes. It still won't mount it, but you will get a better overview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be nothing at all wrong with the drive. It may not be encrypted… but Macs can't read Ext4 without 3rd party software.

There's a freeware option FUSE, but it's always been unstable, so YMMV.
If you have Homebrew installed, then FUSE is accessible with

```
brew install --cask osxfuse
brew install ext4fuse
```

Alternatively, I'd recommend [Paragon's ExtFS for Mac](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/extfs-mac/)

Further info - [MakeTechEasier: How to Mount and Access Ext4 Partition in Mac](https://www.maketecheasier.com/mount-access-ext4-partition-mac/)

Comment: thank you, the ExtFS program worked great

Comment: Glad it worked for you :) I was worried the comments above would lead you in the wrong direction. No-one had spotted the simple fact that the Mac just couldn't read it.